# Instanced object and properties that are references

Tags: javascript

Just when I thought I had JS figured out, I get hung up on this:

```
function Obj() {
    console.log('x: %s, o.x: %s', this.x++, this.o.x++);
}    
Obj.prototype.x = 1;
Obj.prototype.o = {x: 1};
```

Expected:

```
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 1
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 1
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 1
```

Actual:

```
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 1
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 2
> new Obj
x: 1, o.x: 3
```

So, it seems that if a prototypal property is a reference type, then it is shared across all instances, yet if it's a non-reference type then it is reinitialized for each instance; to confirm this hypothesis, I tested a few other types, such as `string` (which behaves like `number`) and `array` (which behaves like `object`).

I have determined that I can avoid this pitfall if I reinitialize the object property in the ctor, like this:

```
function Obj() {
    this.o = {x: 1};
}
```

Which just seems really unorthodox (that I'd be required to manually reinitialize properties *but only if they're a reference object*).

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: `(new Obj).o === (new Obj).o` - the [inherited] properties all point to the same object, whose `x` property you increment.

Comment: *"..such as string (which behaves like number) and array (which behaves like object).."* well, primitives are copied by value (strings, numbers, booleans) while objects (yes, `array` is an object too) are copied by reference. The thing is that when you modify the `x` property of the `o` object, you are modifying the reference to the same `o` object in the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way. You're always going to be modifying the object on which you're operating, irrespective of where the value comes from.

When you do this for the first time:

```
this.x++;
```

It is getting the value of `x` from `Obj.prototype.x` because there was no `x` property directly on the `this` object, nevertheless the `++` is still *operating* on the `this` object, so the value is set on that object. That value is now directly on the instance for future modifications. *(The `prototype.x` is shadowed until the direct property is `delete`d.)*

However, when you do this:

```
this.o.x++
```

The only operation on the `this` object is the lookup of `o`. Since again there is no `o` property on `this`, you'll get the reference to the object stored at `Obj.prototype.o`. At this point, there's no actual modification of the `this` object.

After the reference is returned, you then look up the property `x` on the `Obj.prototype.o` object, and modify it.

So it's actually quite consistent. With `this.o.x++` you've performed a lookup on `this`, but no mutation. The mutation is on the referenced object. But with `this.x++`, you're mutating the object directly.

---

So yes, unless you want your reference types to be shared among all instances created from the constructor, you should put the reference types directly on the instances and not on the `.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks! You confirmed what I suspected (though you articulated it better).

Answer (score 0):

I think the first answer has the gist of it, but I'm answering from a slightly different angle.

The key to understanding it is object behavior in regards to assigning to an object.

Lookups fall back to the prototype if there is no instance property. Always.

Assignments, however, will auto-create a new instance property every time. This won't really matter if you assign a by-reference prototyped property to a new instance property since they both are just pointers to the same thing. And if you mutate in-place, no new instance property will be created either.

```
function Obj(){
    //this.refArr resolves to what's in the prototype and that's what we change
    this.refArr.push(1);

    //now copy sliceArray and assign a new but identical array
    this.sliceArray = this.sliceArray.slice(0);

    //no length increase would mean a new instance property is created
    //... and then the assigment took place.
    this.sliceArray.push(1);
    console.log( 'ref:'+this.refArr.length +', sliceArray:'+this.sliceArray.length);
}
Obj.prototype.refArr = [];
Obj.prototype.sliceArray = [];
new Obj; new Obj;
//ref:1, sliceArray:1
//ref:2, sliceArray:1
```

And that's essentially the difference in what you're doing. `this.x = this.x + 1` creates a new property. Since you assign to a property of `this.constructor.prototype.o` no new property is created. If you incremented and then assigned this.o to this.o it wouldn't matter anyway, since prototype and new property version would just point at the same object.

Comment: Of course `this.refArr = this.refArr;` would create a new property, yet it points to the same array as the inherited property from before. You can easily check by changing `Obj.prototype.refArr`

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misused hasOwnProperty in a test. Fixing.